# NaN con la función asfreq aplicada a un DataFrame

Tags: python

Estoy intentando extraer información de determinados horarios de un DataFrame de Series Temporales.

Convertí mi DataTime en índices por medio de:

`df = df.set_index('data')`

```
                     rad      temp     pot
data            
2018-01-01 00:00:00 0.305   24.26746    0.0
2018-01-01 00:01:00 0.300   23.94263    0.0
2018-01-01 00:02:00 0.300   24.03558    0.0
2018-01-01 00:03:00 0.300   23.94281    0.0
2018-01-01 00:04:00 0.285   24.10493    0.0
... ... ... ...
2019-12-31 23:43:00 0.005   25.99035    0.0
2019-12-31 23:44:00 0.000   25.97606    0.0
2019-12-31 23:45:00 0.000   25.96891    0.0
2019-12-31 23:46:00 0.000   25.98423    0.0
2019-12-31 23:47:00 0.000   25.96458    0.0

940508 rows × 3 columns
```

Luego, como habían índices duplicados (fechas iguales, errores de medición), los eliminé así:

`df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')]`

Finalmente apliqué la función 'asfreq' para extraer solo las filas de hora en hora

`df1 = df.asfreq('60min')`

pero me devuelve un DataFrame con mis otras columnas en `NaN`:

```
 data             rad   temp     pot
2018-01-01 00:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 03:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 04:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ...
2019-12-31 19:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-31 20:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-31 21:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-31 22:00:00 NaN NaN NaN
2019-12-31 23:00:00 NaN NaN NaN

17520 rows × 3 columns
```

No entiendo, ¿por qué me sucede esto?